# Tensorflow model uses way more RAM in linux than in windows in predict mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ram

I'm having problems with my developing and production machines. On the dev side I have a windows machine with 8 GB of RAM and on the production side I use a AWS instance with 2 cores and 8GB of RAM. I am having problems with the production environment when I am using my developed models in that instance. When I execute the project that uses 4 models of Inception ResNetV2 + classifier i get 3 GB of RAM used in Windows. However when I try to execute the same project on that instance only loads 2 models before killing the process due to RAM consumption. I have been checking the RAM consumption executing the project in a screen and using htop on the console to watch the RAM usage. 
It reaches the 8 GB mark and after that linux kills the process.

How it can be possible that using the same requirements lists and same python version, in windows i get 3GB used and in linux it kills due to memory problems?.
This is an example of a model that i am using. All of them are quite similar, some with more neurons on the 3rd addition assignment

```
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(include_top = False, input_shape = (HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3), weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable=False
addition = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
addition = Dropout(0.5)(addition)
addition = Dense(256,activation='relu')(addition)
addition = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(addition)
model = Model(base_model.inputs, addition)
```

Do you have any idea of why does this happpen?
Any feedback wopuld be grateful

Comment: maybe you have a swap file set up under Windows that's saving you, and none under Linux?  also note that each OS will report memory usage differently, so that might be confusing things.  also it might implicitly be using more parallelism under Linux which would use more memory